# How to display a pointed array as a parameter/argument in an function in C?

Tags: c

I have the following problem. I don't know how to pass a pointed array as an argument. I'm trying to feed my array some "random" numbers for it to be passed down as an argument in order to sort them from last to first.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, int size){

    printf("%d\n", tab[0]);
    printf("%d\n", tab[1]);
    printf("%d\n", tab[2]);
    printf("%d\n", tab[3]);
    printf("%d\n", tab[4]);
    printf("%d\n", tab[5]);

    for(int i = size; i>0; i--){   // <- how I'd like it to be
        printf("%d", tab[i]);      // _,,_
    }
}
int main(){

    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4 , e = 5, f = 6, size = 5;
    int *ptrArray[6] = {&a, &b, &c , &d, &e, &f};
    // I already printed out the array here with "printf("%d\n", *ptrArray[(((the actual index)))]);" and it works
    printf("%d!!!\n", *ptrArray[5]);
    ft_rev_int_tab(*ptrArray, size);

    return 0;
}
```

The code prints out normally in the main() function
but if i try to print it out in the "ft_rev_int_tab()" it gives me the location of the pointer.. I think

> OUTPUT: 6!!! // -> location: main
>
> 1
> 2
> 6
> 1
> 0
> -167881014 // -> location: function (there are "\n" between the numbers)

Comment: 1) Why is `size` 5, it’s 6 so it’s confusing? Adjust the for loop logic to use the *correct* size, not a hack. 2) Don’t dereference the array when passing it onto the function.

Comment: `ptrArray` is an array. `*ptrArray` is not an array. It is a pointer that happens to point to the variable `a`. `(*ptrArray)[i]` and thus `tab[i]` is invalid for all `i` except `0`. The code has undefined behavior. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q1eGWjTod).

Comment: You want an array of integers (`int *`). You created an array of *pointers to integers* (`int **`). You pass the first pointer in such array to your function. Even though that pointer will only point to a single integer (`a`) your function thinks it is an array and therefore treats it like one, which is wrong.

Comment: @s3dev because the indexes start with 0.. i think? and 2nd i have no idea what you mean because if i try to use *tab[what ever]" i get errors

Comment: @7Ver7dict7 - 1) The size (number of element in the array) is 6; full stop.  2) Don’t.  Just use `tab[i]`. Otherwise you’re indexing an address —> UB.

Comment: Aside, simplify your life and just create the array as: `int ptrArray[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};`

Comment: You're starting at one _beyond_ the end with: `for(int i = size; i>0; i--)` You want: `for(int i = size - 1; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: @CraigEstey - In most cases, you’d be correct. However, here OP’s `size = 5` for an array length of 6.  Hence my “it’s confusing” comment.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Bugs:

- `ft_rev_int_tab(*ptrArray, size);`. The function expects `int *tab`, meaning an array "decayed" into a pointer to the first element. But there is no array of `int` in place at the address `*ptrArray`, there's just a single item `a` there.

  And so you tell the function "from this address on, you have an array of contiguous `int`". That's not the case, there's no guarantee that the variables a,b,c etc are allocated in contiguous memory. But that's how the function treats them here and that's wrong. It may work by (bad) luck but the code contains undefined behavior and might as well crash or print garbage.
- `size = 5` you probably meant 6 since you have 6 items.
- `for(int i = size; i>0; i--)`. This iterates from index 5 to 1, you probably want 5 to 0. Avoid non-trivial loops like this as they are an easy way to create bugs.

Other things of note:

- In case of `*tab[0]` note that `[]` has higher precedence than `*`. So it will first pick an index in the pointer array, then de-reference that index.
- Since arrays in C start with zero index, one way to iterate backwards inside a plain for loop is `[size-i-1]` where the `-1` ensures that we get zero indexing.

A fixed program might look like this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_rev_int_tab(int size, int* tab[size]){

    printf("%d\n", *tab[0]);
    printf("%d\n", *tab[1]);
    printf("%d\n", *tab[2]);
    printf("%d\n", *tab[3]);
    printf("%d\n", *tab[4]);
    printf("%d\n", *tab[5]);
    printf("\n");

    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) // <-- idiomatic for loop, always try to use this form
      printf("%d\n", *tab[size-i-1]); // this iterates over the array of pointers
}

int main(){
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4 , e = 5, f = 6, size = 6;
    int *ptrArray[6] = {&a, &b, &c , &d, &e, &f};
    
    ft_rev_int_tab(size, ptrArray);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to pass a pointed array as an argument

What a *"pointed array"* is?

Anyway, back to the code

```
    void ft_rev_int_tab(int *tab, int size)
```

is the function and it expects a pointer to `int` and an `int`

In `main` it is called as

```
     ft_rev_int_tab(*ptrArray, size);
```

and

```
      int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4 ,
          e = 5, f = 6, size = 5;
      int *ptrArray[6] = {&a, &b, &c , &d, &e, &f};
```

SO `ptrArray` is `int*[6]` as your compiler or IDE could tell you, like this from Visual Studio:

[image: from VS].

It is an array of pointers to `int`. Since it is an array its address will get passed to the function. Since in the end it is an array of pointer to `int` the compiler may think you know what you are doing, but may be you do not: the function expects the address of an array of `int`.

#### what then?

you can change one side or the other

#### this works changing the function

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ft_rev_int_tab(int* tab[], int size)
{
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d", *tab[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int  a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, size = 5;
    int* ptrArray[6] = {&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f};
    ft_rev_int_tab(ptrArray, size);
    return 0;
}
```

#### this works changing `main`

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ft_rev_int_tab(int* tab, int size)
{
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--)
        printf("%d", tab[i]); 
}

int main(void)
{
    int  a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6, size = 5;
    int ptrArray[6] = {a, b, c, d, e, f};
    ft_rev_int_tab(ptrArray, size);
    return 0;
}
```

#### And this is the most common way

Passing a pointer to a pointer to `int` is more convenient

```
#include <stdio.h>
void ft_rev_int_tab(int** tab, int size)
{
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--)
        printf("[%i]=%d\n", i,*tab[i]);
}

int main(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    int e = 5;
    int f = 6;
    int size = 5;
    int* ptrArray[6] = {&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f};
    printf("value pointed to by last pointer: %d\n", *ptrArray[5]);
    ft_rev_int_tab(ptrArray, size);
    return 0;
}
```

```
value pointed to by last pointer: 6
[5]=6
[4]=5
[3]=4
[2]=3
[1]=2
```

[How to display a pointed array as a parameter/argument in an function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78057711/how-to-display-a-pointed-array-as-a-parameter-argument-in-an-function-in-c)